# A* circular path finding algorithm with restrictions

Tags: graph-algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I have a road map represented as a directed graph of junctions and links leading from one junction to another, each link is weighted with it's own traversal time (the time it takes to cross the link) and im asked to find an algorithm to get from junction A to junction B and back from junction B to junction A so that the total path cost (in time) takes no longer than 10% more time than the optimal path cost (that is the path cost returned by A* algorithm) while keeping the time overlaps of the path to B and the path from B to a minimum, that is if t(x,y) represents the time to cross link (x,y) i need to bring to minimum the sum of t(x,y) + t(y,x) for the links that overlap.
the algorithm should be optimal for the problem at hand and complete (it should also be efficient) and probably use some variants of A* like A*epsilon and the likes...

does anyone have a clue how to go about this problem?
i was thinking of representing the states of this problem as (junction,flag) where flag indicates whether the current node is a part of a path that already passed junction B and the goal state is (A,True) and then using A*epsilon on this... but i don't know how to take into account the time overlap issue.. i guess what im suggesting is not the way im intended to solve this.
any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I know this isn't exactly an answer, but I used to read some fascinating articles about A* pathfinding. Make sure you've done a fair amount of googling - you might be surprised what you find with the right search. (I like what I see with "a star pathfinding"

Comment: I have done a lot of googling and found nothing close to this, all the A* problems i have found are dealing with finding a path from a source node to a target node without taking into consideration finding a path that passes through a certain node with minimum overlap between the path before the node and the path after the node as in this case.